# Javascript using local value into other function

Tags: javascript, php, variables, authentication, global

I am currently using a login function on my page, with that i wanna use the username submitted somewhere else to use this for other purposes.

My login javascript file is as following

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        console.log("click");

        var jsonp = {
              username: $("#username").val(),
              password: $("#password").val(),
              is_ajax: 1
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://myurl.com/login.php",
            data: jsonp,
            success: function(response) {
                if (response == 'success') {
                     window.location = "homepage.html";

                } else {
                     alert("wrong username password combination")
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

In this same file i wanna use the username that is submitted for other purposes so outside of that function. How can i do that?

Comment: `window.localStorage.setItem('username', theUsernameFromOtherThing);` then in your function (or page load) access `window.localStorage.getItem('username');`

Comment: You could set a cookie just before calling `window.location = "homepage.html"`

Comment: Make it a `homepage.php` that *knows* the username of the logged-in user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use any Server languages. You can just use `window.localStorage.setItem('username', theUsernameFromOtherThing);` as suggested by @Paul S

However if you want also want to use a server language(such as PHP) I recommend a **cookie**, but beware of storing secure data in a cookie, since anyone sniffing can just grab it.

Also if you are sending you username and password to a url on another server, you better check that your domain, and the domain you are posting to, starts with **https**.

I highly recommend Sitepoint for their very simplified guides. http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-deal-with-cookies-in-javascript/ if you wan't to learn basic web development.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery cookie plugin, the link as working today: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

**Create session cookie:**

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

**Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:**

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
```

**Create expiring cookie, valid across entire site:**

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

**Read cookie:**

```
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => "the_value"
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => undefined
```

**Read all available cookies:**

```
$.cookie(); // => { "the_cookie": "the_value", "...remaining": "cookies" }
```

**Delete cookie:**

```
// Returns true when cookie was found, false when no cookie was found...
$.removeCookie('the_cookie');

// Same path as when the cookie was written...
$.removeCookie('the_cookie', { path: '/' });
```